# mongodb equivalent for MYSQL concat()

Tags: mysql, mongodb, concatenation

I would like to search the `user` collection by `first_name` and `last_name` keyed in as `full_name` in the search query. The search query for the `full_name` would be the `first_name` separated by a 'blank space', followed by the `last_name`. Both `first_name` and `last_name` may have blank spaces. In mysql I would do this something like

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE(CONCAT(users.first_name, users.last_name) == 'Peter Griffin')
```

NOTE: I'm using `mongo -v 2.2.0` and I thought that [concat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/concat/) could work, but I could not test it since `2.2.0` doesn't support the concat function

Is there a way to achieve the above query in mongodb?

Comment: Why not split the string into first and last names and search for that?

Comment: @WiredPrairie Yeah, I know I could, but as I have mentioned in the question both `first_name` and `last_name` could have blank spaces. For eg, how would you search for `first_name='Peter Löwenbräu'` and `last_name='Griffin'` and the user enters the search query as "Peter Löwenbräu Griffin", would you split 'Peter Griffin' as first name or 'Löwenbräu Griffin' as last name?

Comment: You need to normalize the data and remove spaces, etc. regardless. Maybe store the names as a fullName to optimize for this search.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, your comment makes sense from the optimization point of view. Moving forward I could design the collection in such a way it would be benificial in the long run, but I'm looking for a flexible solution to concatenate the values of the two keys and then compare against it.

Comment: The reason I'm not suggesting something else is because it doesn't exist in MongoDB.

Comment: What about actually adding a new string into the users documents that is fullname? You should of course remove whitespaces before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
db.users.find( { $where: function() { return (this.first_name.concat(this.last_name) == "Peter Griffin") } } );
```

Comment: Of course you would have to be pretty crazy to let that run on your system, $where is bad enough without its index usage

Comment: Any better suggestion is pretty much appreciated and i gladly update this answer with it. Does aggregation styled $concat use an index?

Comment: Nah, tbh there is no good way of doing this, it is still one of the flaws of MongoDB, it needs a concat op. One way could be to project a concat doc in aggregation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/concat/ and then do a $match, not sure if that would use indexes though, edit: nope, this won't use indexes even then